# Как объединить столбцы из разных таблиц в одну таблицу в visual studio C# winforms?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каждый турист может выбрать от одного до нескольких туров, которые он хочет посетить. Когда он оформляет путевку, в данных о путевке содержится как id туриста, так и Id тура, который приобрел турист. Как я могу объединить данные из разных таблиц (datagridview1 и datagridview2) в одну таблицу (datagridview3).

Answer (score 0):

Создай в базе данных отдельную таблицу "Путевки" со столбцами `id путевки`, `id туриста`, `id тура` и работай с ней как тебе хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря, я справился с этой задачей. Публикую код. Может быть он кому-нибудь пригодится.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView4.RowCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView4.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        string SqlExpression = "INSERT INTO `Putevky`(`Kod_Turista`, `Kod_Tura`) VALUES ('" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "', '" + dataGridView4.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "')";
                        MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(SqlExpression, Conn);
                        commandDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Записано!");
                    }   
                }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]